# how do I refresh the textbox/datatable to re-run this command?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, textbox, datatable, refresh

This piece of code grabs a customers hire record using their hire ID and displays their details in multiple textboxes. It all works fine and well, however, I can only run it once. If I type in another customers hire record ID it just displays the first customers details that were materialised, which I assume is because the datatable has been populated and not refreshed based on the new hire record ID I've entered.

```
    Private Sub Button6_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click

    Dim hirerecord1 As Integer = TextBox13.Text

    Dim cmd2 As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM HireItemRecord WHERE HireRecord_Id = " & hirerecord1, cnn)
    Dim sqlDa As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd2)

    sqlDa.Fill(dt1)
    If dt1.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        TextBox14.Text = dt1.Rows(0)("RentalItem_Id").ToString()  
        TextBox15.Text = dt1.Rows(0)("HireRecord_Id").ToString()
        TextBox45.Text = dt1.Rows(0)("HireItemBeginDate").ToString()

    End If
    cnn.Close()

End Sub
```

I'm not quite sure what to do to fix this...

Also, I'm having a similar problem with this..

```
Private Sub TextBox46_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox46.TextChanged
    Dim keywords2 As String = TextBox46.Text

    ds1.Tables("PersonDetails").DefaultView.RowFilter = "Last_Name like '%" & keywords2 & "%' "
End Sub
```

With this I can search a column of a datagridview for a match. It works all fine and well, until I insert a new record into the database at which point I refresh the datagridview to display the newly added record. After I do this, I can no longer search using the textbox. Once again, I'm not quite sure what to do to fix this issue.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're closing your connection at the end of the `Button6_Click` method and I can't see where it gets opened again. That would fit with your symptoms of the method only running successfully once. Have you tried to step through the code to see where it fails the second time?

Comment: thanks for your reply. Yes I've tried closing and opening the connection. Same thing though unforunately, I hit the button again and it just displays the same details that were previously pulled from the database into the textboxes.

Comment: Your code looks fine - is it possible the SQL statement is pulling back more than one record and you're always displaying the first record in the result set?

Comment: wow I just figured it out. what I needed to do was to clear the datatable completely as well as restart the connection because when the command runs it displays the data in the very first row, and when I select another record it adds it to the next row so it wasn't showing up. Thanks for your help though! Any idea how to refresh the textbox? :P

Comment: hahahahaha! sorry I didn't see your reply, yep, that's exactly what it was!

Comment: I suspect it's something to do with `ds1` - do you need to repopulate/rebind it to the datagrid after you've added a new record?